# Bitbake: How to include a change from `meta/lib/oe/` into my Yocto build?

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I am building a linux image with an older version of Yocto. Lets say the version I am building is [Sumo](http://downloads.yoctoproject.org/releases/yocto/yocto-2.5/).

I want a change from [Zeus](http://downloads.yoctoproject.org/releases/yocto/yocto-3.0/). If it was something from `recipes-support` for instance, then I know that I just have to add the recipe in my own layer. This is good and standard procedure. I know this part well.

But, what if I want a change in `sources/poky/meta/lib/oe/utils.py` which is `Zeus` but not in `Sumo` version of Yocto? Is it possible to get that change by using recipe? If yes, then how to get it in a standard Yocto recipes way?

Comment: The answer depends completely on the specifics of the case: you might be able to take the Zeus utility functionality and reproduce it inside your recipe so your recipe no longer uses the old utility functionality -- then a recipe change is enough. Otherwise you might be able to have a simple patch to yocto sources. Or the change might be so tricky to port that it just doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to merge the change from zeus into your own sumo-based branch.
How easy or not that is depends entirely on the change though.